# $select isn't working while $filter and $select=* works

Tags: c#, angular, angularjs, odata

I'm working to get employees from database:

```
/api/employee/v1/employees
```

I want to filter first if "isInactive eq false" and then I want to $select only "firstName,lastName,empNumber" only. But if I use $select, the array I get is different and holds a "instance:null" instead.

In this image I first have response from just using $filter, then underneath I also add $select=* to see if it works:

[Image: $filter, then $filter&$select=*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxgQB.png)

```
/api/employee/v1/employees?$filter=isInactive eq false`
// and
/api/employee/v1/employees?$filter=isInactive eq false&$select=*`
```

The response Array without the $select looks different than the other one with. So there's already an issue here that I don't understand. Though I can see the correct response in the "instance" and "untypedInstance" containers??

In this next image I try to use:

```
/api/employee/v1/employees?$select=firstName&$filter=isInactive eq false`
```

And here I only get null, see image: [Image: $select=firstName](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6L91G.png)

---

What am I doing wrong?

I would want to write something like: /api/employee/v1/employees?$select=*&$filter=isInactive eq false&$top=3` only because I just happen to get empNumber, firstName and lastName first in those wierd containers. I have to make this $select work!

Comment: You are using the wrong tag, use `angularjs` instead